# Filter a string using regular expression

Tags: regex, autoit

I tried the following code. However, the result is not what I want.

```
$strLine = "100.11 Q9"
$sortString = StringRegExp ($strLine,'([0-9\.]{1,7})', $STR_REGEXPARRAYMATCH)
MsgBox(0, "", $sortString[0],2)
```

The output shows `100.11`, but I want `100.11 9`. How could I display it this way using a regular expression?

Comment: Is the result `100.11 9` wanted to be one string? Or as a 2 element array with `100.11` and `9`?

Comment: yeah just 100.11 9 to be one string, because I actually gonna use it to compare with other string, thank you for giving me an idea that how I can do, because I am kind of new to regexp, I really want to learn it well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sPattern = "([0-9\.]+)\sQ(\d+)"

$strLine = "100.11 Q9"
$sortString = StringRegExpReplace($strLine, $sPattern, '\1 \2')
MsgBox(0, "$sortString", $sortString, 2)

$strLine = "100.11 Q9"
$sortString = StringRegExp($strLine, $sPattern, 3); array of global matches.
For $i1 = 0 To UBound($sortString) -1
    MsgBox(0, "$sortString[" & $i1 & "]", $sortString[$i1], 2)
Next
```

The pattern is to get the 2 groups being `100.11` and `9`.

The pattern will 1st match the group with any digit and dot until it reach
`/s` which will match the space. It will then match the `Q`. The 2nd group
matches any remaining digits.

`StringRegExpReplace` replaces the whole string with 1st and 2nd groups
separated with a space.

`StringRegExp` get the 2 groups as 2 array elements.

Choose 1 from the 2 types regexp above of which you prefer.